# How to hint to m2e (Maven plugin for eclipse) to attach external javadoc website to artifact?

Tags: eclipse, maven, javadoc, m2eclipse

I need to use artifact X which does not have neither source nor javadoc artifacts available.  I know, however, an external web server where the javadoc for X has been publicized.

In "plain" Eclipse I can attach an URL as the Javadoc Location for a jar in the build path, and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> opens a browser to that URL.

I would like to have m2e do the same automatically for artifact X without changing the artifacts from Maven Central.

Sample pom.xml showing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>m2e-javadoc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>ASCII</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jt400</groupId>
            <artifactId>jt400-full</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

How do I hint this?

---

EDIT:  Question has been asked on m2e mailing list at http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg02386.html

---

EDIT: After some experiments installing missing artifacts in local repository and giving up on having the project do a Maven release, I repackaged the latest version (7.10) to Maven Central.

Comment: When you say 'neither source nor javadoc available', do you mean that on maven central neither the javadoc nor the sources are available, or that the sources or javadoc are not in the local repo? If the sources are in the local repo, then maven automatically recognises them.

Comment: @MatthewFarwell Not in Central and not locally.  This happens so frequently - especially with elder projects which are not mavenized, but the result is pushed to Central - that a simple solution inside our source repository is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it won't work if the creator didn't create the appropriate artifacts (-sources and -javadoc) for the particular artifact. But you should be able to manually add the javadoc for an particular artifact. I would suggest to create a separate package (artifact-javadoc) and deploy it to your repository manager than it should work automaticially.

Comment: This is exactly what I do not want to do.  If I can configure m2e to look elsewhere, that will be fine.

Comment: I know this answer is not what the OP wants to do, but IMO it is the right answer because it will using Maven's versioning capability to keep the artifact JAR and the javadoc/source in sync.  Otherwise, you might use v2.0.0 for the JAR and be looking at v2.1.0 Javadoc/Source.  I do think that a script to make a Javadoc JAR from a publicized web site could be useful...

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Maven Javadoc Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/) for [this scenario](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/links-configuration.html) by augmenting your POM:

> You could add cross reference links to external projects using the
>    parameters. For instance:

```
<project>
  ...
  <reporting> (or <build>)
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <links>
            <link>http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/</link>
            <link>http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/</link>
          </links>
            ...
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting> (or </build>)
  ...
</project>
```

> Important Note: according the Javadoc specifications, all given links
>   should have a fetchable /package-list file.

This strategy can be further augmented by using the [`<offlineLinks/>`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/javadoc-mojo.html#offlineLinks) parameter and the [aggregate goal](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/examples/aggregate.html) to consolidate your documentation into the same documentation tree as desired.

The [documentation for Maven Javadoc Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/) provides additional scenarios and examples involving alternative Javadoc facilities, should you wish to pursue those as well.

Comment: A quick test did not indicate that m2e picks up this hint.  Shift-F2 still says the jar does not have javadoc attached.  Have you actually tried this?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I have. From what I understand, you'll need to run the Maven goal `javadoc:javadoc` or `javadoc:aggregate` at least once in terminal, and set your project's _Javadoc Location_ to the generated documentation (`$PROJECT/target/site/apidocs`) to make this work. It's obtrusive, but to my knowledge, Maven Javadoc plugin is the standard Mavenized way to do this.

Comment: The suggested method allows for merging in external javadoc in your own, but not in what I actually need.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I think you may be asking for a tool or workflow that does not yet exist for Eclipse. To my knowledge, these are the current facilities that are provided. If you wish to stay entirely inside of Eclipse for them, you will need only to build the `javadoc` goals within Eclipse and point your Javadoc Location to the output directory. -- I don't think any more magic is provided by m2e, which is a shame; [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)'s Maven integration handles all of these things.

Comment: We have IntelliJ 9.  Can you point me to a page explaining how to set this?

Comment: I require that value to be set correctly, yes.  Unfortunately (in this case) m2e manage it automatically.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I see. So, as before: you need it to be specified for the _artifact_ instead of just a JAR. Hmn, I don't think that's supported. -- But, going back to IJ: when it bundles in Maven dependencies, it _should_ also resolve external Javadoc links as specified above. What happens when you use this same POM in IJ and attempt to access the documentation for particular classes or methods from X?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Whoops. Forgot the link you requested: http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=612, which should integrate happily with any docs you pull into IJ, be it through Maven or otherwise.